# How do speed up date range select in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Here is my query:

```
    const tags = await db.queryEntries(
      "SELECT tag, count(tag) AS count, created_at FROM tags WHERE DATE(created_at) >= DATE('now', '-1 days') GROUP BY tag ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 100"
    );
```

Here is my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE tags (
            tag TEXT,
            url STRING
        , created_at TEXT);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tag_url ON tags (tag, url)
                        ;
CREATE INDEX idx_tags_created_at ON tags(created_at);
```

It's still very slow (30+ seconds) when I run the query there are about 1.5 million records in the db for tags.

Here are the results of `EXPLAIN`:

```
addr  opcode         p1    p2    p3    p4             p5  comment      
----  -------------  ----  ----  ----  -------------  --  -------------
0     Init           0     56    0                    00  Start at 56  
1     OpenEphemeral  1     5     0     k(1,-B)        00  nColumn=5    
2     Integer        100   1     0                    00  r[1]=100; LIMIT counter
3     Noop           2     2     0                    00               
4     Integer        0     6     0                    00  r[6]=0; clear abort flag
5     Null           0     9     9                    00  r[9..9]=NULL 
6     Gosub          8     46    0                    00               
7     OpenRead       0     7     0     3              00  root=7 iDb=0; tags
8     OpenRead       3     3693502  0     k(3,,,)        00  root=3693502 iDb=0; tag_url
9     Rewind         3     28    11    0              00               
10      DeferredSeek   3     0     0                    00  Move 0 to 3.rowid if needed
11      Column         0     2     12                   00  r[12]=tags.created_at
12      Function       0     12    11    date(-1)       00  r[11]=func(r[12])
13      Lt             13    27    11                   50  if r[11]<r[13] goto 27
14      Column         3     0     10                   00  r[10]=tags.tag
15      Compare        9     10    1     k(1,-B)        00  r[9] <-> r[10]
16      Jump           17    21    17                   00               
17      Move           10    9     1                    00  r[9]=r[10]   
18      Gosub          7     32    0                    00  output one row
19      IfPos          6     49    0                    00  if r[6]>0 then r[6]-=0, goto 49; check abort flag
20      Gosub          8     46    0                    00  reset accumulator
21      Column         3     0     11                   00  r[11]=tags.tag
22      AggStep        0     11    3     count(1)       01  accum=r[3] step(r[11])
23      If             5     26    0                    00               
24      Column         3     0     2                    00  r[2]=tags.tag
25      Column         0     2     4                    00  r[4]=tags.created_at
26      Integer        1     5     0                    00  r[5]=1; indicate data in accumulator
27    Next           3     10    0                    01               
28    Gosub          7     32    0                    00  output final row
29    Goto           0     49    0                    00               
30    Integer        1     6     0                    00  r[6]=1; set abort flag
31    Return         7     0     0                    00               
32    IfPos          5     34    0                    00  if r[5]>0 then r[5]-=0, goto 34; Groupby result generator entry point
33    Return         7     0     0                    00               
34    AggFinal       3     1     0     count(1)       00  accum=r[3] N=1
35    Copy           3     14    0                    00  r[14]=r[3]   
36    Sequence       1     15    0                    00  r[15]=cursor[1].ctr++
37    IfNotZero      1     41    0                    00  if r[1]!=0 then r[1]--, goto 41
38    Last           1     0     0                    00               
39    IdxLE          1     45    14    1              00  key=r[14]    
40    Delete         1     0     0                    00               
41    Copy           2     16    0                    00  r[16]=r[2]   
42    Copy           4     17    0                    00  r[17]=r[4]   
43    MakeRecord     14    4     19                   00  r[19]=mkrec(r[14..17])
44    IdxInsert      1     19    14    4              00  key=r[19]    
45    Return         7     0     0                    00  end groupby result generator
46    Null           0     2     4                    00  r[2..4]=NULL 
47    Integer        0     5     0                    00  r[5]=0; indicate accumulator empty
48    Return         8     0     0                    00               
49    Sort           1     55    0                    00               
50      Column         1     3     18                   00  r[18]=created_at
51      Column         1     0     17                   00  r[17]=count  
52      Column         1     2     16                   00  r[16]=tag    
53      ResultRow      16    3     0                    00  output=r[16..18]
54    Next           1     50    0                    00               
55    Halt           0     0     0                    00               
56    Transaction    0     0     8     0              01  usesStmtJournal=0
57    String8        0     20    0     now            00  r[20]='now'  
58    String8        0     21    0     -1 days        00  r[21]='-1 days'
59    Function       3     20    13    date(-1)       00  r[13]=func(r[20])
60    Goto           0     1     0                    00
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the query so that it is *sargable* (i.e. it can take advantage of an index):

```sql
SELECT tag, COUNT(tag) AS count
FROM tags
WHERE created_at >= strftime('%Y-%m-%d', 'now', '-1 days')
GROUP BY tag
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

The above query should benefit from the following index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON tags (created_at, tag);
```

Comment: Ahh so because I'm dynamically changing the date value the index is ignored?

Comment: @chovy If you use `DATE(created_at)` in the `WHERE` clause, then SQLite can't use an index on `created_at`.  There are some databases, such as Oracle, which support function indices.  But SQLite does not support this AFAIK, hence I gave you a workaround.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make any difference speed wise. maybe the bottleneck is somewhere else. from the command line sqlite console its only a few seconds. my app takes 30+ seconds still. Could RAM be issue? I have 4gb.

Comment: Off the top of my head, if your `WHERE` clause only filters off very few rows, then the index won't help much.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that if `WHERE` removes a lot of records, that would make the rest of the query pipeline much faster.  Therefore, if so, an index on `created_on` would then make the entire query fast, and vice-versa.

Comment: yeah i mean theres months worth of data and were filtering for just 1 day...so it should be fast.

Comment: Now I'm getting `Error: database disk image is malformed` sometimes. but not everytime.